# HTML embedded video won't play unless "disable cache" is enabled in DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, https, html5-video

I'm making a website [named bobPlayer](https://bob.bildsben.tech), and for some reason it will not load a MP4 file transmitted over HTTPS. It simply shows the following: [Link to screenshot of player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFech.png)

Trying to press the play button, or pressing space will not play the video.

The video works fine [when caching is disabled via DevTools in chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNzo.png)

In the header section of my actual HTML code I have contained the following meta tags, yet Chrome still refuses to play the video:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

This issue does NOT occur in Safari/Chrome on iOS, however me and 2 other friends are encountering the issue on PC. (Specifically Chrome only, it seems to work fine in Firefox.)

The server that these videos are being hosted on runs Ruby, and is authenticated via HTTPS, since the website does not allow mixed content of HTTP and HTTPS.

The server hosts MP4 files of these videos. This shouldn't be the cause of my problems, since all modern web browsers support MP4. The server is running off Ruby in the comman line using the following command:

`ruby -run -e httpd . --ssl-certificate=/home/pi/.ssl/certificate.crt --ssl-private-key=/home/pi/.ssl/private.key -p 8010`

The webpage decides which video to play via a script which matches the URL tag `?episode=123` to a url hosted within a JSON file. The video trying to be played is within the limit of 1-405. This issue also occurs if trying to play the video through a tag that isn't dynamically allocated, where the source file is coded into the HTML file, not replaced with the JS code.

All code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/bildsben/bobPlayer), however the videos are not hosted there, rather on [a Ruby httpd server](https://bildsben.hopto.org:8010) as mentioned earlier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The status code for the MP4 is 206 Partial Content. I am on edge latest version.

Comment: Given that the issue can be reproduced without JS or Ruby, I'd suggest removing those tags, and showing the smallest-relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet it is a video format issue.  iOS supports h265 encoding in all browsers while Chrome on Windows does not.  What is the encoding of the video file?  You can test with https://ffprobe.a.video (and add the url of the video).

Comment: The website says that the formatting is h264. When pasting the link in chrome, it just downloads the file, not playback the file. I assume its some other meta data that is causing the video not to work.